# Lumia Imaging SDK 3.0 Blending AutoEnhance Effect and other source throw InvalidArgumentException

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, blending, lumia-imaging-sdk

I am trying to blend an existing image with another `IImageProvider` that has an `Effect` applied. I noticed there are are several `Effect`s that throw InvalidArgumentException such as the `Auto Enhance` and `Auto Levels`.  Many other `Effect`s such as the `Antique` effect does not throw this error.

[image: untitled-1]

My code:

```
    . . .
SoftwareBitmapImageSource streamTextBitmapForeground = new SoftwareBitmapImageSource(normalizedTextSoftwareBitmap);

//using (SharpnessEffect sharpenText = new SharpnessEffect(streamTextBitmapForeground, SettingsPart.SharpnessLevel))
using (BlendEffect blendEffect = new BlendEffect(effectBackground, streamTextBitmapForeground, BlendFunction.Normal, 1.0f))
using (BitmapRenderer bitmapRenderer = new BitmapRenderer(blendEffect))
{

    Bitmap bitmap = await bitmapRenderer.RenderAsync();
    byte[] pixelBuffer = bitmap.Buffers[0].Buffer.ToArray();

    using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        var pngEncoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);

        pngEncoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
            BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
            (uint)bitmap.Dimensions.Width,
            (uint)bitmap.Dimensions.Height,
            displayInformation.LogicalDpi,
            displayInformation.LogicalDpi,
            pixelBuffer);

        await pngEncoder.FlushAsync().AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);

        . . .
```

The error is raised at `Bitmap bitmap = await bitmapRenderer.RenderAsync();`

Perhaps I need to set some parameters like the imagesize or something but I can't figure out what I am missing from the error message. I've tried using several overloads but still no go. Any ideas?

Comment: Just tested your code, I can't reproduce your issue...Could you please provide more detailed information? Or could you please provide a sample?

Comment: Hi @Grace Feng. I am using the EditShowcase sample from Lumia Imaging SDK GitHub. I obtained  the effectBackground using `IImageProvider effectBackground = (SelectedEffect.GetEffectAsync(imageProcessorRenderer.M_Source, imageProcessorRenderer.M_SourceSize, imageProcessorRenderer.RenderSize)).Result;` I think the return value  is causing the problem during the blending process. Because when I render it to SoftwareBitmap first then blend it, the error was not raised.

Comment: Yes, since you didn't post the code of your `effectBackground `, I rendered it to `SoftwareBitmap` first, that's exactly why I can't reproduce your Issue. I'will keep digging in this case.

Comment: Looks like something is null when you try to render. Are you sure you are not attempting to blend with an effect that requires more input? Also, there are some known bugs when it comes to GPU processing, so perhaps give it a try when rendering on CPU only: set the renderer.RenderOptions = RenderOptions.CPUOnly to try it, and please report back if that fixed your problem.

Comment: @PutraKg Any updates? Have you tried David's suggestion?

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT Not yet because I've decided to render it to `SoftwareBitmap` first before blending and the error isn't raised.. But I will try @David's suggestion to confirm and  will update my finding. Thanks.

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT I've tested using `RenderOptions.Cpu` and the error is gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue.

As [David Božjak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55377/david-bo%C5%BEjak) mentioned, there are some known issues for GPU processing, you might try to set `RenderOptions` as CPU only.

```
using (BitmapRenderer bitmapRender = new BitmapRenderer(blendeffect))
{
          bitmapRender.RenderOptions = RenderOptions.Cpu;
          Bitmap bitmap = await bitmapRender.RenderAsync();
}
```

Verified on the Win10 14393 PC.

Comment: Verified working with `RenderOptions.Cpu` on Win10 14393

Comment: @PutraKg Good to know;)